# run a Matlab code in cmd and wait for it to finish

Tags: c++, createprocess, waitforsingleobject

I want to run a matlab code in my c++ programme and wait for the results of Matlab and then continue to my c++ code. the problem is that the programme does not wait for matlab and continue their running. 
should I add anything to my code?

actually I tried to create process and used WaitForSingleObject.

```
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );


    system("matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -nodisplay -r run('Main')");

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

.
.
.
}
```

Comment: You're mixing two different and *incompatible* ways of running external programs. The [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function is a standard C++ function, it will block until the program you execute finishes. The `STARTUPINFO` and `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structures, and the handles and `WaitForSingleObject` and `CloseHandle` is for the Windows API funciton [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), which is a completely different system of running programs.

Comment: so, what should I do? I also used only system("matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -nodisplay -r run('Main')"); but it does not wait for it

Comment: If the program you run starts its own processes and let them run in the background while the main process exits, then it doesn't matter how you run the program. If there's a way to tell the program to not exit early you need to use that. Otherwise you need to come up with another way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the option

```
-batch
```

to matlab instead of the option

```
-r
```

Eg. see this page for more detail: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html

---

Additionally the `std::system` call is *'standalone'* - however you should check the return of the process launched.

```
int ret = std::system("....");
if (ret != 0) {
  std::terminate();//somethings not right...
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. it is now solved. I used -wait; system("matlab.exe -wait -nosplash -nodesktop -nodisplay -r run('Main')");